# Any reason why scala does not explicitly support dependent types?

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type, dependent-type, shapeless

There are path dependent types and I think it is possible to express almost all the features of such languages as Epigram or Agda in Scala, but I'm wondering why Scala does not support [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type) more explicitly like it does very nicely in other areas (say, DSLs) ?
Anything I'm missing like "it is not necessary" ?

Comment: Well, the designers of Scala believe that the Barendregt Lambda Cube isn't the be-all-end-all of Type Theory. That might or might not be the reason.

Comment: @JörgWMittag What is the Lamda Cube? Some sort of magic device ?

Comment: @ashy_32bit see Barendregt's paper "Introduction to Generalised Type Systems" here: http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/henglein/papers/barendregt1991.pdf

Answer (score 159):

Syntactic convenience aside, the combination of singleton types, path-dependent types and implicit values means that Scala has surprisingly good support for dependent typing, as I've tried to demonstrate in [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

Scala's intrinsic support for dependent types is via [path-dependent types](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/papers/mfcs06.pdf). These allow a type to depend on a selector path through an object- (ie. value-) graph like so,

```
scala> class Foo { class Bar }
defined class Foo

scala> val foo1 = new Foo
foo1: Foo = Foo@24bc0658

scala> val foo2 = new Foo
foo2: Foo = Foo@6f7f757

scala> implicitly[foo1.Bar =:= foo1.Bar] // OK: equal types
res0: =:=[foo1.Bar,foo1.Bar] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[foo1.Bar =:= foo2.Bar] // Not OK: unequal types
<console>:11: error: Cannot prove that foo1.Bar =:= foo2.Bar.
              implicitly[foo1.Bar =:= foo2.Bar]
```

In my view, the above should be enough to answer the question "Is Scala a dependently typed language?" in the positive: it's clear that here we have types which are distinguished by the values which are their prefixes.

However, it's often objected that Scala isn't a "fully" dependently type language because it doesn't have [dependent sum and product types](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1299) as found in Agda or Coq or Idris as intrinsics. I think this reflects a fixation on form over fundamentals to some extent, nevertheless, I'll try and show that Scala is a lot closer to these other languages than is typically acknowledged.

Despite the terminology, dependent sum types (also known as Sigma types) are simply a pair of values where the type of the second value is dependent on the first value. This is directly representable in Scala,

```
scala> trait Sigma {
     |   val foo: Foo
     |   val bar: foo.Bar
     | }
defined trait Sigma

scala> val sigma = new Sigma {
     |   val foo = foo1
     |   val bar = new foo.Bar
     | }
sigma: java.lang.Object with Sigma{val bar: this.foo.Bar} = $anon$1@e3fabd8
```

and in fact, this is a crucial part of the [encoding of dependent method types which is needed to escape from the 'Bakery of Doom'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861070/146737) in Scala prior to 2.10 (or earlier via the experimental -Ydependent-method types Scala compiler option).

Dependent product types (aka Pi types) are essentially functions from values to types. They are key to the representation of [statically sized vectors](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~hwxi/DML/DML.html) and the other poster children for dependently typed programming languages. We can encode Pi types in Scala using a combination of path dependent types, singleton types and implicit parameters. First we define a trait which is going to represent a function from a value of type T to a type U,

```
scala> trait Pi[T] { type U }
defined trait Pi
```

We can than define a polymorphic method which uses this type,

```
scala> def depList[T](t: T)(implicit pi: Pi[T]): List[pi.U] = Nil
depList: [T](t: T)(implicit pi: Pi[T])List[pi.U]
```

(note the use of the path-dependent type `pi.U` in the result type `List[pi.U]`). Given a value of type T, this function will return a(n empty) list of values of the type corresponding to that particular T value.

Now let's define some suitable values and implicit witnesses for the functional relationships we want to hold,

```
scala> object Foo
defined module Foo

scala> object Bar
defined module Bar

scala> implicit val fooInt = new Pi[Foo.type] { type U = Int }
fooInt: java.lang.Object with Pi[Foo.type]{type U = Int} = $anon$1@60681a11

scala> implicit val barString = new Pi[Bar.type] { type U = String }
barString: java.lang.Object with Pi[Bar.type]{type U = String} = $anon$1@187602ae
```

And now here is our Pi-type-using function in action,

```
scala> depList(Foo)
res2: List[fooInt.U] = List()

scala> depList(Bar)
res3: List[barString.U] = List()

scala> implicitly[res2.type <:< List[Int]]
res4: <:<[res2.type,List[Int]] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[res2.type <:< List[String]]
<console>:19: error: Cannot prove that res2.type <:< List[String].
              implicitly[res2.type <:< List[String]]
                    ^

scala> implicitly[res3.type <:< List[String]]
res6: <:<[res3.type,List[String]] = <function1>

scala> implicitly[res3.type <:< List[Int]]
<console>:19: error: Cannot prove that res3.type <:< List[Int].
              implicitly[res3.type <:< List[Int]]
```

(note that here we use Scala's `<:<` subtype-witnessing operator rather than `=:=` because `res2.type` and `res3.type` are singleton types and hence more precise than the types we are verifying on the RHS).

In practice, however, in Scala we wouldn't start by encoding Sigma and Pi types and then proceeding from there as we would in Agda or Idris. Instead we would use path-dependent types, singleton types and implicits directly. You can find numerous examples of how this plays out in shapeless: [sized types](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/sized.scala), [extensible records](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/records.scala), [comprehensive HLists](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlist.scala), [scrap your boilerplate](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/sybclass.scala), [generic Zippers](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/zipper.scala) etc. etc.

The only remaining objection I can see is that in the above encoding of Pi types we require the singleton types of the depended-on values to be expressible. Unfortunately in Scala this is only possible for values of reference types and not for values of non-reference types (esp. eg. Int). This is a shame, but not an intrinsic difficulty: Scala's type checker represents the singleton types of non-reference values internally, and there have been a [couple](http://existentialtype.net/2008/07/21/literally-dependent-types/) of [experiments](https://github.com/paulp/scala/tree/topic/literal-dot-type) in making them directly expressible. In practice we can work around the problem with a [fairly standard type-level encoding of the natural numbers](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/nat.scala).

In any case, I don't think this slight domain restriction can be used as an objection to Scala's status as a dependently typed language. If it is, then the same could be said for Dependent ML (which only allows dependencies on natural number values) which would be a bizarre conclusion.

Comment: Can you provide an example how this can look like?

Comment: Example of what, exactly? Sized vectors? See shapeless.

Comment: I mean an example that shows dependent types in action - how to create them, how to use them.

Comment: @MilesSabin Look who is here to answer my humble question, no less than the author of shapeless himself. I have been trying to get my head around shapless for a week now. Very nice work indeed Miles.It would be nice if you provided a little theoretical background in a tutorial or something to alleviate the impedance mismatch.

Comment: Miles, thanks for this very detailed answer. I'm a bit curious about one thing, though. None of your examples seem at first glance particularly impossible to express in Haskell; are you then claiming that Haskell is also a dependently-typed language?

Comment: I downvoted because I can't distinguish the techniques here in essence from the techniques described in McBride's "Faking It" http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.2636 -- i.e. these are ways to simulate dependent types, not provide them directly.

Comment: @sclv I think you've missed that Scala has dependent types without any form of encoding: see the first example above. You're quite right that my encoding of Pi types uses some of the same techniques as Connor's paper, but from a substrate that already includes path-dependent types and singleton types.

Comment: @JonathanSterling dependent types are the future, so it'd be astonishing if GHC didn't have capabilities which take you all or part of the way there ;-) Conor McBride's paper describing an encoding of dependent types in Haskell mentioned by sclv in these comments predates the arrival of GADTs and type families and they bring dependently typed features even closer.

Comment: Nope. Sure you can have types tied to objects (this is a consequence of objects as modules). But you can't have computation on these types without using value-level witnesses. In fact =:= itself is a value-level witness! You're still faking it, just like you have to in Haskell, or perhaps more so.

Comment: "tied to" is a circumlocution for "depending on".

Comment: You're ignoring the second part of my comment. And "tied to" is much less powerful than "depending on" in general, since the only thing you can do is have them "inside" objects, not "depending on" in any computationally interesting way!

Comment: @sclv Can you point to a definition of "depending on" in the literature which excludes path dependent types?

Comment: @sclv What is meant with "value-level witnesses" supposedly being a precluding characteristic of a non-dependently typed language? A value is a proof of the proposition put forth as the type signature.

Comment: Scala's =:= isn't value-level, it's a type constructor - a value for that is here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L445, and doesn't seem particularly different than a witness for an equality proposition in dependently-typed languages like Agda and Idris: refl. (See http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~abel/Equality.pdf section 2, and http://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/writings/idris-tutorial.pdf section 8.1, respectively.)

Answer (score 6):

I would assume it is because (as I know from experience, having used dependent types in the Coq proof assistant, which fully supports them but still not in a very convenient way) dependent types are a very advanced programming language feature which is really hard to get right - and can cause an exponential blowup in complexity in practice. They're still a topic of computer science research.

Comment: would you be kind enough to give me some theoretical background to dependant types (a link perhaps) ?

Comment: @ashy_32bit if you can get access to "Advanced Topics in Types and Programming Languages" by Benjamin Pierce, there is a chapter in that which gives a reasonable introduction to dependent types. You could also read some papers by Conor McBride who has a particular interest in dependent types in practice rather than in theory.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Scala's path-dependent types can only represent Σ-types, but not Π-types. This:

```
trait Pi[T] { type U }
```

is not exactly a Π-type. By definition, Π-type, or dependent product, is a function which result type depends on argument value, representing universal quantifier, i.e. ∀x: A, B(x). In the case above, however, it depends only on type T, but not on some value of this type. Pi trait itself is a Σ-type, an existential quantifier, i.e. ∃x: A, B(x). Object's self-reference in this case is acting as quantified variable. When passed in as implicit parameter, however, it reduces to an ordinary type function, since it is resolved type-wise. Encoding for dependent product in Scala may look like the following:

```
trait Sigma[T] {
  val x: T
  type U //can depend on x
}

// (t: T) => (∃ mapping(x, U), x == t) => (u: U); sadly, refinement won't compile
def pi[T](t: T)(implicit mapping: Sigma[T] { val x = t }): mapping.U
```

The missing piece here is an ability to statically constraint field x to expected value t, effectively forming an equation representing the property of all values inhabiting type T. Together with our Σ-types, used to express the existence of object with given property, the logic is formed, in which our equation is a theorem to be proven.

On a side note, in real case theorem may be highly nontrivial, up to the point where it cannot be automatically derived from code or solved without significant amount of effort. One can even formulate Riemann Hypothesis this way, only to find the signature impossible to implement without actually proving it, looping forever or throwing an exception.

Comment: Miles Sabin has above shown an example of using `Pi` to create types depending on values.

Comment: In the example, `depList` extracts type `U` from the `Pi[T]`, selected for type (not value) of `t`. This type just happens to be singleton type, currently available on Scala singleton objects and representing their exact values. Example creates one implementation of `Pi` per singleton object type, thus pairing type with value as in Σ-type. Π-type, on the other hand, is a formula that matches over the structure of its input parameter. Possibly, Scala don't have them because Π-types require every parameter type to be GADT, and Scala don't distinguish GADTs from other types.

Comment: Okay, I am a bit confused. Wouldn't `pi.U` in Miles' example count as dependent type? It's on the value `pi`.

Comment: It indeed counts as dependent type, but there's different flavors of those: Σ-type ("there exists x such that P(x)", logic-wise) and Π-type ("for all x, P(x)"). As you noted, type `pi.U` is dependent on value of `pi`. Problem that preventing `trait Pi[T]` from becoming a Π-type is that we can't make it dependent on value of an arbitrary argument (for example, `t` in `depList`) without lifting that argument at type level.

Answer (score 1):

The question was about using dependently typed feature more directly and, in my opinion,
there would be a benefit in having a more direct dependent typing approach than what Scala offers.
Current answers try to argue the question on type theoretical level. 
I want to put a more pragmatic spin on it.
This may explain why people are divided on the level of support of dependent types in the Scala language. We may have somewhat different definitions in mind. (not to say one is right and one is wrong).

This is not an attempt to answer the question how easy would it be to turn
Scala into something like Idris (I imagine very hard) or to write a library 
offering more direct support for Idris like capabilities (like `singletons` tries to be in Haskell).

Instead, I want to emphasize the pragmatic difference between Scala and a language like Idris.
What are code bits for value and type level expressions?
Idris uses the same code, Scala uses very different code.

Scala (similarly to Haskell) may be able to encode lots of type level calculations. 
This is shown by libraries like `shapeless`.
These libraries do it using some really impressive and clever tricks. 
However, their type level code is (currently) quite different from value level expressions
(I find that gap to be somewhat closer in Haskell). Idris allows to use value level expression on the type level AS IS.

The obvious benefit is code reuse (you do not need to code type level expressions 
separately from value level if you need them in both places).  It should be way easier to 
write value level code.  It should be easier to not have to deal with hacks like singletons (not to mention performance cost). You do not need to learn two things you learn one thing.
On a pragmatic level, we end up needing fewer concepts. Type synonyms, type families, functions, ... how about just functions?  In my opinion, this unifying benefits go much deeper and are more than syntactic convenience.

Consider verified code. See:
https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/v1.3.0/libs/contrib/Interfaces/Verified.idr
Type checker verifies proofs of monadic/functor/applicative laws and the 
proofs are about actual implementations of monad/functor/applicative and not some encoded
type level equivalent that may be the same or not the same.
The big question is what are we proving?

The same can me done using clever encoding tricks (see the following for Haskell version, I have not seen one for Scala)
https://blog.jle.im/entry/verified-instances-in-haskell.html
https://github.com/rpeszek/IdrisTddNotes/wiki/Play_FunctorLaws
except the types are so complicated that it is hard to see the laws, the value 
level expressions are converted (automatically but still) to type level things and 
you need to trust that conversion as well. 
There is room for error in all of this which kinda defies the purpose of compiler acting as
a proof assistant.

(EDITED 2018.8.10) Talking about proof assistance, here is another big difference between Idris and Scala. There is nothing in Scala (or Haskell) that can prevent from writing diverging proofs:

```
case class Void(underlying: Nothing) extends AnyVal //should be uninhabited
def impossible() : Void = impossible()
```

while Idris has `total` keyword preventing code like this from compiling.

A Scala library that tries to unify value and type level code (like Haskell `singletons`) would be an interesting test for Scala's support of dependent types.  Can such library be done much better in Scala because of path-dependent types?

I am too new to Scala to answer that question myself.