# StringOrInt from Idris -> Scala?

Tags: scala, idris

[Type Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) presents this program:

```
StringOrInt : Bool -> Type
StringOrInt x = case x of
                  True => Int
                  False => String
```

How can such a method be written in Scala?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alexey's answer is good, but I think we can get to a more generalizable Scala rendering of this function if we embed it in a slightly larger context.

Edwin shows a use of `StringOrInt` in the function `valToString`,

```
valToString : (x : Bool) -> StringOrInt x -> String
valToString x val = case x of
                         True => cast val
                         False => val
```

In words, `valToString` takes a `Bool` first argument which fixes the type of its second argument as either `Int` or `String` and renders the latter as a `String` as appropriate for its type.

We can translate this to Scala as follows,

```
sealed trait Bool
case object True extends Bool
case object False extends Bool

sealed trait StringOrInt[B, T] {
  def apply(t: T): StringOrIntValue[T]
}
object StringOrInt {
  implicit val trueInt: StringOrInt[True.type, Int] =
    new StringOrInt[True.type, Int] {
      def apply(t: Int) = I(t)
    }

  implicit val falseString: StringOrInt[False.type, String] =
    new StringOrInt[False.type, String] {
      def apply(t: String) = S(t)
    }
}

sealed trait StringOrIntValue[T]
case class S(s: String) extends StringOrIntValue[String]
case class I(i: Int) extends StringOrIntValue[Int]

def valToString[T](x: Bool)(v: T)(implicit si: StringOrInt[x.type, T]): String =
  si(v) match {
    case S(s) => s
    case I(i) => i.toString
  }
```

Here we are using a variety of Scala's limited dependently typed features to encode Idris's full-spectrum dependent types.

- We use the singleton types `True.type` and `False.type` to cross from the value level to the type level.
- We encode the function `StringOrInt` as a type class indexed by the singleton `Bool` types, each case of the Idris function being represented by a distinct implicit instance.
- We write `valToString` as a Scala dependent method, allowing us to use the singleton type of the `Bool` argument `x` to select the implicit `StringOrInt` instance `si`, which in turn determines the type parameter `T` which fixes the type of the second argument `v`.
- We encode the dependent pattern matching in the Idris `valToString` by using the selected `StringOrInt` instance to lift the `v` argument into a Scala GADT which allows the Scala pattern match to refine the type of `v` on the RHS of the cases.

Exercising this on the Scala REPL,

```
scala> valToString(True)(23)
res0: String = 23

scala> valToString(False)("foo")
res1: String = foo
```

Lots of hoops to jump through, and lots of accidental complexity, nevertheless, it can be done.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, Miles. Does using `shapeless` to answer this question provide any improvement to your answer?

Comment: As Alexy mentioned in his answer, shapeless has facilities (eg. `Witness`) which make it easier to use the singleton types of primitive values, so you could use `Boolean` and `true` and `false` rather that the `Bool` and  `True` and `False` that I invented above. That might be helpful in some practical contexts, but I don't think it adds anything from a general understanding point of view.

Answer (score 10):

This would be one approach (but it's a lot more limited than in Idris):

```
trait Type {
  type T
}

def stringOrInt(x: Boolean) = // Scala infers Type { type T >: Int with String }
  if (x) new Type { type T = Int } else new Type { type T = String }
```

and then to use it

```
def f(t: Type): t.T = ...
```

If you are willing to limit yourself to literals, you could use singleton types of `true` and `false` using Shapeless. From [examples](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala):

```
import syntax.singleton._

val wTrue = Witness(true)
type True = wTrue.T
val wFalse = Witness(false)
type False = wFalse.T

trait Type1[A] { type T }
implicit val Type1True: Type1[True] = new Type1[True] { type T = Int }
implicit val Type1False: Type1[False] = new Type1[False] { type T = String }
```

See also [Any reason why scala does not explicitly support dependent types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935731/any-reason-why-scala-does-not-explicitly-support-dependent-types), http://www.infoq.com/presentations/scala-idris and http://wheaties.github.io/Presentations/Scala-Dep-Types/dependent-types.html.

Comment: I'm afraid I've just noticed that there's a problem with your `stringOrInt` definition: you've ascribed the type `Type` as the result ... this explicitly drops the refinements that you've computed in the body. OTOH, if you allow the result type to be inferred it will be `Type { type T >: Int with String }` irrespective of the value of `x`.

Comment: I think you've still not got a dependency on the value of `x` though ... the result type is `Type { type T >: Int with String }` irrespective of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that `getStringOrInt` example has not been implemented by either of the two answers

```
getStringOrInt : (x : Bool) -> StringOrInt x
getStringOrInt x = case x of
      True => 10
      False => "Hello"
```

I found Miles Sabin explanation very useful and this approach is based on his. 
I found it more intuitive to split GADT-like construction from Scala apply() trickery and try to map my code to Idris/Haskell concepts. I hope others find this useful. I am using GADT explicitly in names to emphasize the GADT-ness.
The 2 ingredients of this code are: GADT concept and Scala's implicits.

Here is a slightly modified Miles Sabin's solution that implements both `getStringOrInt` and `valToString`.

```
sealed trait StringOrIntGADT[T]
case class S(s: String) extends StringOrIntGADT[String]
case class I(i: Int) extends StringOrIntGADT[Int]

/* this compiles with 2.12.6
   before I would have to use ah-hoc polymorphic extract method */
def extractStringOrInt[T](t: StringOrIntGADT[T]) : T =
 t match {
  case S(s) => s
  case I(i) => i
 }
/* apply trickery gives T -> StringOrIntGADT[T] conversion */
sealed trait EncodeInStringOrInt[T] {
   def apply(t: T): StringOrIntGADT[T] 
}
object EncodeInStringOrInt {
 implicit val encodeString : EncodeInStringOrInt[String] = new EncodeInStringOrInt[String]{
        def apply(t: String) = S(t)
     }
 implicit val encodeInt : EncodeInStringOrInt[Int] = new EncodeInStringOrInt[Int]{
        def apply(t: Int) = I(t)
     }
 } 
 /* Subtyping provides type level Boolean */
 sealed trait Bool
 case object True extends Bool
 case object False extends Bool

 /* Type level mapping between Bool and String/Int types. 
    Somewhat mimicking type family concept in type theory or Haskell */
 sealed trait DecideStringOrIntGADT[B, T]
 case object PickS extends DecideStringOrIntGADT[False.type, String]
 case object PickI extends DecideStringOrIntGADT[True.type, Int]

 object DecideStringOrIntGADT {
   implicit val trueInt: DecideStringOrIntGADT[True.type, Int] = PickI
   implicit val falseString: DecideStringOrIntGADT[False.type, String] = PickS
 }
```

All this work allows me to implement decent versions of `getStringOrInt` and `valToString`

```
def pickStringOrInt[B, T](c: DecideStringOrIntGADT[B, T]): StringOrIntGADT[T]=
  c match {
    case PickS => S("Hello")
    case PickI => I(2)
  }

def getStringOrInt[T](b: Bool)(implicit ev: DecideStringOrIntGADT[b.type, T]): T =
  extractStringOrInt(pickStringOrInt(ev))

def valToString[T](b: Bool)(v: T)(implicit ev: EncodeInStringOrInt[T], de: DecideStringOrIntGADT[b.type, T]): String =
  ev(v) match {
    case S(s) => s
    case I(i) => i.toString
  }
```

All this (unfortunate) complexity appears to be needed, for example this will not compile

```
//  def getStringOrInt2[T](b: Bool)(implicit ev: DecideStringOrIntGADT[b.type, T]): T =
//    ev match {
//      case PickS => "Hello"
//      case PickI => 2
//    }
```

I have a pet project in which I compared all code in the Idris book to Haskell.
https://github.com/rpeszek/IdrisTddNotes/wiki 
(I am starting work on a Scala version of this comparison.)

With type-level Boolean (which is effectively what we have here) `StringOrInt` examples become super simple if we have type families (partial functions between types). See bottom of 
https://github.com/rpeszek/IdrisTddNotes/wiki/Part1_Sec1_4_5

This makes Haskell/Idris code is so much simpler and easier to read and understand.

Notice that `valToString` matches on `StringOrIntGADT[T]/StringOrIntValue[T]` constructors and not directly on Bool. That is one example where Idris and Haskell shine.

Comment: Any reason the code is different here https://github.com/rpeszek/IdrisTddScalaNotes/blob/master/src/main/scala/part1/Sec1_4_5_StringOrIntAsGADT.scala ?