# Is Peano number type indexing a sigma or pi dependent type?

Tags: scala, types, dependent-type

So I came across dependent typing at Scala Exchange (at [this](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/9045-an-introduction-to-dependent-typing-in-scala) talk), and the speaker went through an example where he indexed a vector using Peano numbers and used it to encode properties about operations on vector in the types of those operations - I've also seen this a few other places since as well. I read more about dependent types [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), but I couldn't quite translate the example above into sigma/pi dependent type distinction.

So, my question is: are the types being used in the Peano-indexed vector sigma or pi dependent types? Also, could someone please provide or point me to an example of the kind that they're *not* so I have a examples of both? (preferably in Scala)

Comment: Wikipedia's presentation of dependent type theory is a bit reductionist in my opinion. Not everything we use in dependently typed programming is a pi-type or a sigma-type. Vectors are an _inductive family_.

Comment: Okay, well, do you perhaps know of a good place to get a better overview? So far most of my research has only produced quite involved papers and documents that I don't have the time to get my head around.

Comment: My favourite introduction is Oury and Swierstra's [_The Power of Pi_](https://cs.ru.nl/~wouters/Publications/ThePowerOfPi.pdf) which gives some examples of dependently-typed programs with real-world applicability. [The Agda tutorial](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/afp08/tutorial.pdf) is also quite good. And Brady has [a work-in-progress book](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) about Idris.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12937819/1374461) to a different question might interest you.