# How to specify return type for nested arrays of arbitrary nesting length?

Tags: arrays, scala, return-type

Suppose, as an example, I want a function that recursively wraps an array in another array, `n` times.

In other words, the desired outcome is:

```
wrap(Array(1,2,3), 2) = Array(Array(Array(1,2,3)))
wrap(Array(4,5,6), 3) = Array(Array(Array(Array(4,5,6))))
```

How does one specify the return type? It depends on `n`. Assuming the input is of type `Array[A]`:

For `n=1`, it's `Array[Array[A]]`.

For `n=3`, it's `Array[Array[Array[Array[A]]]]`

We could use `Array[_]` like:

```
def wrap[A:ClassTag](x:Array[A], n:Int):Array[_] = { 
  if (n == 1) {
    Array(x)
  } else {
    wrap(Array(x), n-1)
  }
}
```

but then the compiler doesn't know that the elements are `Array`s:

```
> val y = wrap(Array(1,2,3), 1)
  Array[_] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3))
> y(0).length
error: value length is not a member of _$1
  y(0).length
       ^
```

We can use `asInstanceOf`, but that doesn't seem like a great solution:

```
> y(0).asInstanceOf[Array[Int]].length
  Int = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array[_]` is the correct type for a method such as that, but not all type information has been lost. You can use pattern matching to retrieve it.

```
def unwrap(a :Array[_]) :String = a match {
  case Array(sa :Array[_]) => unwrap(sa)
  case ia :Array[Int]      => ia.mkString("+")
  case x                   => x.mkString("-")
}
```

That being said, it's best to avoid arbitrary-nesting types altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a perfect solution is possible, since the value of `n` is determined at runtime, but the return type needs to be there at compile time. If `n` is ever not a literal, as in your examples, then probably the best you can do is return an `Array[_]`.

But if you are always going to be using a literal, then you can essentially pass `n` at compile time as a type parameter. Instead of passing `n=1`, you pass `A=Array[Array[Int]]`:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait Wrapper[A, B] {
  def wrap(xs: Array[B]): A
}

implicit def wrapperBase[B] = new Wrapper[Array[B], B] {
  def wrap(xs: Array[B]) = xs
}

implicit def wrapperRec[A : ClassTag, B](implicit w: Wrapper[A, B]) = new Wrapper[Array[A], B] {
  def wrap(xs: Array[B]): Array[A] = Array(w.wrap(xs))
}

def wrap[B, A](xs: Array[B])(implicit w: Wrapper[A, B]): A = w.wrap(xs)

val xs = Array(1, 2, 3)
wrap[Int, Array[Array[Int]]](xs)  // instead of wrap(xs, 1)
wrap[Int, Array[Array[Array[Int]]]](xs)  // instead of wrap(xs, 2)
```

If you want to get *really* fancy you can get into compile-time integer types ala shapeless's `Nat` class and in theory do things like `wrap[Int, _5]` but that's definitely a bigger rabbit hole for little benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do it in a simple way. Types are compile-time citizens, and numbers live at runtime. Consider what happens if the number `n` is read from the user input. For different future user inputs the compiler should generate different result types for the method.

If I'm not wrong, for that we would need a language with a better support for dependent types than Scala. See this question: [Any reason why scala does not explicitly support dependent types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935731/any-reason-why-scala-does-not-explicitly-support-dependent-types) and especially [the answer by P. Frolov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43333106/1098230) there.

That said, it's possible to express that type if the number `n` is known at compile-time. For example it's an `Int` literal, a `final val`, or some simple arithmetic expression of literals and `final val`s. For example in case of `final val a = 3; wrap(Array(1,2,3), a * 2 + 1)`.

Here is a sample code of a typeclass, that implements that wrapping. It uses the `shapeless` library for its nice conversions of number literals to `Nat` type values:

```
import scala.reflect.{classTag, ClassTag}

abstract class Wrapper[T : ClassTag, N <: Nat] {
  // Type of Array[T] wrapped N times
  type Out 

  // ClassTag of the array wrapped N times. 
  // It's needed to be able to wrap it one more time.
  def outTag: ClassTag[Out]

  // The actual function that wraps the array
  def apply(array: Array[T]): Out 
}

object Wrapper {
  type Aux[T, N <: Nat, O] = Wrapper[T, N] { type Out = O }

  // Wrap the array 0 times. The base of the recursion.
  implicit def zero[T : ClassTag]: Aux[T, Nat._0, Array[T]] = new Wrapper[T, Nat._0] {
    type Out = Array[T]
    def outTag = classTag[T].wrap
    def apply(array: Array[T]): Out = array
  }

  // Given a Wrapper, that wraps the array N times,
  //   make a Wrapper, that wraps N + 1 times.
  implicit def next[T : ClassTag, N <: Nat](
    implicit prev: Wrapper[T, N]
  ): Aux[T, Succ[N], Array[prev.Out]] = new Wrapper[T, Succ[N]] {
    type Out = Array[prev.Out]
    def outTag = prev.outTag.wrap
    def apply(array: Array[T]): Out = Array(prev(array))(prev.outTag)
  }
}
```

And the wrap function that uses this typeclass:

```
def wrap[A: ClassTag](
  x: Array[A], 
  n: Nat
)(
  implicit wrapper: Wrapper[A, n.N]
): wrapper.Out = 
  wrapper(x)
```

The compiler knows the type of the result, and can use the result without any typecasts:

```
scala> val a = wrap(Array(1,2,3), 3)
a: Array[Array[Array[Array[Int]]]] = Array(Array(Array(Array(1, 2, 3))))

scala> a.head.head.head.sum
res1: Int = 6

scala> object Foo {
  final val n = 2
  def run() = wrap(Array(1,2,3), n * 2 + 1)
} 
defined object Foo

scala> Foo.run()
res2: Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Array[Int]]]]]] = Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(Array(1, 2, 3))))))
```

Comment: Well, I alluded to something just like this in my answer but didn't actually go and do it since it seemed significantly tricky. So kudos for actually doing it!

Comment: @JoeK Yes, it's interesting as a sort of a puzzle, but I agree that the practical usability is rather questionable.