# Scala: how to force converting a statement to literal?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, dependent-type, refined

I'm experimenting the refined type feature of scala provided in one of its library:

https://github.com/fthomas/refined

The following code represents a simple case:

```
  import eu.timepit.refined.auto._
  import shapeless.{Witness => W}

    type Vec5 = List[Int] Refined Size[Equal[W.`5`.T]]

    val v1: Vec5 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

    val v2: Vec5 = List(1 to 5: _*)
```

When attempting to compile it I got the following error:

```
[Error] /home/peng/git/scalaspike/common/src/test/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/refined_spike/Example.scala:32: compile-time refinement only works with literals
[Error] /home/peng/git/scalaspike/common/src/test/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/refined_spike/Example.scala:34: compile-time refinement only works with literals
[Error] /home/peng/git/scalaspike/common/src/test/scala/com/tribbloids/spike/singleton_ops_spike/Example.scala:32: Cannot prove requirement Require[...]
three errors found
```

It should be noted that both v1 & v2 can be easily evaluated at compile time and inlined, however scala compiler seems to refuse to do that, and for `List` type there seems to have no way to suggest this.

So how could this feature be useful?

Comment: `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` is not a literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that `eu.timepit.refined` macros work for literals, `BigDecimal`, `BigInt`

https://github.com/fthomas/refined/blob/master/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/eu/timepit/refined/macros/RefineMacro.scala#L14-L23

```
def impl[F[_, _], T: c.WeakTypeTag, P: c.WeakTypeTag](t: c.Expr[T])(
    rt: c.Expr[RefType[F]],
    v: c.Expr[Validate[T, P]]
): c.Expr[F[T, P]] = {
  val tValue: T = t.tree match {
    case Literal(Constant(value)) => value.asInstanceOf[T]
    case BigDecimalMatcher(value) => value.asInstanceOf[T]
    case BigIntMatcher(value)     => value.asInstanceOf[T]
    case _                        => abort(Resources.refineNonCompileTimeConstant)
  }
```

`List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` is not a literal.

For not literal values like `List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` there is `refineV` working at runtime

```
val v1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val v2 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
refineV[Size[Equal[5]]](v1) 
// Right(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
refineV[Size[Equal[5]]](v2) 
// Left(Predicate taking size(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) = 6 failed: Predicate failed: (6 == 5).)
```

Fortunately you can run `refineV` at compile time

```
object myAuto {
  implicit def compileTimeRefineV[T, P](t: T): T Refined P = 
    macro compileTimeRefineVImpl[T, P]

  def compileTimeRefineVImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag, 
                             P: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(t: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val pTyp = weakTypeOf[P]
    val tTyp = weakTypeOf[T]
    c.eval(c.Expr[Either[String, T Refined P]](c.untypecheck(
      q"_root_.eu.timepit.refined.`package`.refineV[$pTyp].apply[$tTyp]($t)"
    ))).fold(
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, _),
      _ => q"$t.asInstanceOf[_root_.eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined[$tTyp, $pTyp]]"
    )
  }
}

import myAuto._ // don't import eu.timepit.refined.auto._
type Vec5 = List[Int] Refined Size[Equal[5]]
val v1: Vec5 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // compiles
// val v2: Vec5 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
  // Error: Predicate taking size(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) = 6 failed: Predicate failed: (6 == 5).
```

If you just need statically-sized collection you can use `shapeless.Sized`

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#collections-with-statically-known-sizes

Comment: Thanks a lot, the answer apparently was written in scala 2.13, I'll try to reproduce it in 2.12.

Comment: The reason I prefer to avoid Shapeless.Sized is that it uses Nat type which relies on church encoding, which is not efficient

Comment: @tribbloid In 2.12. you just need to replace type `5` with ``W.`5`.T`` (`import eu.timepit.refined.W`). Everything else should work.

Comment: @tribbloid I [asked](https://gitter.im/fthomas/refined?at=5eca59944412600ccd64654f) **fthomas** aka [Frank S. Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460387/frank-s-thomas) at gitter: *"wouldn't it be a good idea to implement implicit conversions not only for literals?"*. His [answer](https://gitter.im/fthomas/refined?at=5ed63c999da05a060a47c69e): *"If we allow refining arbitrary values at compile-time, we would allow running arbitrary code at compile-time. If the expression passed to `refineV` has side-effects, we would run them at compile-time."*

Answer (score 8):

Judging by [tests](https://github.com/fthomas/refined/search?p=1&q=size+equal&unscoped_q=size+equal) the `Size[Equals[X]]` compile-time lifting is only implemented in macros for `String` literals.

And BTW, this makes sense, because author would have to evaluate the code at compile time - `List(1,2,3,4,5)` might look easy, but `Set(1,1,2,2,3,3)` would require some evaluation, and what if the code to evaluate was `List(1,1,2,2,3,3).distinct` - it also could be resolved in compile time but you have to set line somewhere unless you want to risk arbitrary code execution. And even in simpler cases the ADT to analyze could be hairy and error prone. Sure, it would be possible to add some "obvious special cases" but personally, I prefer that the library's author focuses on something more useful instead.

Comment: This is why I'm asking if scala has a keyword to declare a literal for List type. In most modern compiler architecture there is no clear boundary between compile time and runtime.

Comment: Scala has literals only for: `String`s, symbols, `null` and some primitives, see: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#literals

Comment: I see, wow that seems like quite a distance to full dependent type. I'll see if I can find other bypasses

Comment: Well, Scala never claimed that it had full dependent types. It implemented a subset, path dependent types, and improved the idea in Dotty, but full dependent types are never a goal. Still it works out most of the time, check Miles Sabin post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935731/any-reason-why-scala-does-not-explicitly-support-dependent-types