# Int Refined Positive doesn't compile

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-3, refined

The followfing code doesn't compile:

```scala
import eu.timepit.refined._
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
import eu.timepit.refined.auto._
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric._

val i1: Int Refined Positive = 5
```

The error is:

```
[error] Found:    (5 : Int)
[error] Required: Int Refined eu.timepit.refined.numeric.Positive
[error] val i1: Int Refined Positive = 5
```

I used `Scala 3.2.2` and latest Refined `eu.timepit::refined:0.10.2`

According to documentation https://github.com/fthomas/refined it shoud compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refined implicit conversions `eu.timepit.refined.auto._` are macro-based (Scala 2 macros):

https://github.com/fthomas/refined/blob/v0.10.2/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala-3.0-/eu/timepit/refined/auto.scala#L58-L68 (Scala 2)

https://github.com/fthomas/refined/blob/v0.10.2/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala-3.0+/eu/timepit/refined/auto.scala (Scala 3)

```
// Scala 2
implicit def autoRefineV[T, P](t: T)(implicit
  rt: RefType[Refined],
  v: Validate[T, P]
): Refined[T, P] = macro RefineMacro.impl[Refined, T, P]
```

**Scala 2 macros do not expand in Scala 3**

[image: refined macros not yet available]

https://scalacenter.github.io/scala-3-migration-guide/docs/macros/macro-libraries.html

So the code you provided compiles in Scala 2: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/aj78AodyQkK1b9F66RXTsA/3

but not in Scala 3: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/aj78AodyQkK1b9F66RXTsA/1

See the ticket *Macros missing for Scala 3* https://github.com/fthomas/refined/issues/932

The issue is that Refined Scala 2 macros use `context.eval`.
What `c.eval` does is transforming (compiling, evaluating) an abstract syntax tree (AST) into the value of this tree:

[Scala: what can code in Context.eval reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935330/scala-what-can-code-in-context-eval-reference/)

[Def Macro, pass parameter from a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132189/def-macro-pass-parameter-from-a-value)

[Scala: how to force converting a statement to literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979101/scala-how-to-force-converting-a-statement-to-literal)

Compile-time `c.eval` used in macros is similar to runtime `toolbox.eval` used in [runtime compilation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes)

[How can I run generated code during script runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73911801/how-can-i-run-generated-code-during-script-runtime) (Scala 2)

[How to compile and execute scala code at run-time in Scala3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945320/how-to-compile-and-execute-scala-code-at-run-time-in-scala3) (Scala 3)

`c.eval` is absent in Scala 3. More precisely, in Scala 3  [there is](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/staging.html) `staging.run` similar to `tb.eval` but it's [forbidden](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#scope-extrusion) in Scala 3 macros because this would violate the [phase consistency principle](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#the-phase-consistency-principle) (PCP). Indeed, `c.eval`/`tb.eval`/`staging.run` transforms a tree (a value from a previous stage) into the value of this tree (a value from a next stage).

Sometimes `c.eval` can be emulated in Scala 3 (but starting from a source code rather than tree): [get annotations from class in scala 3 macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390113/get-annotations-from-class-in-scala-3-macros)

In order to use actual `c.eval`/`tb.eval`/`staging.run` (starting from a tree) in Scala 3 macros, one would need to patch Scala 3 compiler: https://github.com/DmytroMitin/dotty-patched (or maybe a compiler plugin would be enough).

---

Scala 2 macros: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html

Scala 3 macros: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html

Scala 2 macros to Scala 3 macros migration guide: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-metaprogramming.html

Comment: So the issue with Scala 3 is still unresolved I assume

Comment: @Bondarenko Unresolved, indeed.

Comment: https://msitko.pl/blog/build-your-own-refinement-types-in-scala3.html https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/poor-or-rich-mans-refinement-types-in-scala-3-x/4647