# Idiomatic Kotlin way of working with lists we know won't be empty

Tags: kotlin

I avoid using the not-null `!!` operator because it reduces confidence that the code won't crash at runtime.  And I also avoid list operations that can cause a crash if the list is empty, such as `maxBy` (as opposed to `maxByOrNull`).  But sometimes avoiding both of these at the same time feels impossible.  Here's an example:

```kotlin
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int, val height: Int)
val people: List<Person> = // Initialize a list of people

println("Tallest person for each age:")
people.groupBy{it.age}.forEach{ age, peopleWithThisAge ->
    val tallestPersonForThisAge = peopleWithThisAge.maxByOrNull { it.height }!!
    println("$age: ${tallestPersonForThisAge.name}")
}
```

I know that `peopleWithThisAge` will never be empty because `groupBy` only creates lists with at least one value.  But the complier doesn't know that.  Is there an elegant way to handle this situation?

Even when I, as a human reading the code, know that the code won't crash, I want to avoid the mental burden of someone else having to read a bunch of code to understand that.  If I wanted that mental burden, I would still be programming in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what some programming languages solve by using [dependent types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338709/what-is-dependent-typing), that is, types coupled with values (like, a list type marked with the size).

Kotlin can't do that yet, and as long as the types of an empty list and a non-empty one are the same, the compiler can't really help with empty-checks unless it has some other tricks. The closest thing in the Kotlin language features to what could help here is [contracts](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/contracts), but those don't have anything for empty/non-empty states of collections as of now.

Some community projects attempt to provide non-empty collection types for Kotlin:

- [`quickbirdstudios/NonEmptyCollections`](https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/NonEmptyCollections) (see the [blog post](https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/non-empty-lists-kotlin/));
- [`gildor/knel`](https://github.com/gildor/knel)
- [`arrow-kt`](https://arrow-kt.io/) – [part of `arrow-core-data`](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/arrow/core/nonemptylist/)

Here's a feature request for non-empty collections in Kotlin: [KT-21217](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21217/Non-empty-collections)

With the standard library, you can still somewhat reduce the burden on others reading your code by using asserting functions – [`check`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check.html), [`require`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html), [`checkNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check-not-null.html), [`requireNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require-not-null.html), [`error`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/error.html) – and providing meaningful messages, like this:

```kotlin
people.groupBy { it.age }.forEach { age, peopleWithThisAge ->
    val tallestPersonForThisAge = checkNotNull(
        peopleWithThisAge.maxByOrNull { it.height }
    ) { "groupBy creates non-empty groups" }

    println("$age: ${tallestPersonForThisAge.name}")
}
```

The functions `check` and `require` are marked with the according contracts: if they return without throwing an exception, the condition is satisfied. So the compiler can infer some conditions based on the calls to them, too.

Comment: Oh that's fascinating and cool.  Is it correct to say that Kotlin's smart casting is a form of dependent typing?  That is, if an object is nullable we can't use it as an arg for a function that needs non-nullable **unless** we check `if(x != null)` first.

Answer (score 1):

I think these are the choices you have in the standard library. Since it doesn't have non-empty Collection types, you unfortunately can't get compile-time safety, if that's what you mean by elegant.

1. Go ahead and use `maxBy()`. By using it you are asserting that you know it should be safe to use. I consider this is the clean way to do it when working with a collection in the same scope that you created it. Cleaner than `maxByOrNull()!!` since the error message will be more appropriate if you were wrong.
2. Maybe not super concise, but you can use `maxByOrNull()` with an Elvis operator and default. This might be elegant in situations where it's appropriate to have a default. `.maxByOrNull { it.height } ?: 0.0`
3. Use `maxByOrNull()` with an Elvis and an `error` call. This is basically like using `maxBy()!!` but with better messaging. `maxByOrNull { it.height } ?: error("collection was empty")

An improvement on no. 1 that builds on no. 3 might be to create a chain function for asserting the collection isn't empty. Something like:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.assertNotEmpty() =
    (this as? Collection<T> ?: toList()).also {
        require(it.isNotEmpty()) { "Not empty assertion failed." }
    }
```

Then you could call this before calling `maxBy` so later when you're reviewing code, the `maxBy` call won't be as likely to raise eyebrows.