# Type hint a variable constrained to be between to numbers

Tags: python

In many statistical applications, I'd like to type hint variables to be between two numbers (usually 0 and 1).

It would be best to hint that these variables are of type `Interval[low, hi]` or similar.  How can I type hint this in python?

Comment: it sounds like you want *dependent types*, but Python's type system doesn't really have that (indeed, it is not a common feature in most widely used languages

Comment: See [this for some more theoretical discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338709/what-is-dependent-typing). I redirected the duplicate target, the original one had an accepted answer that did't do what was being implied by the title (rather, they used type annotations to enforce constraints *at runtime*)