# Passing number in range as a prop in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following props interface in my component:

```js
export interface ComponentProps {
  title: string;
  value: number;
}
```

However, I need to veryfy that this value is a number in range from 0 to 24.

The only way I could find to do that so far is to use a union type:

```js
value: 0 | 1 | 2 ... | 24;
```

Looks ugly... Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Seeing as you only need a range starting from 0, you could also use a simpler solution like this: https://tsplay.dev/N9jdVm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical term for this sort of thing (a number that's in a specific range) is ["dependent types"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9338709/25507), which is not something that TypeScript attempts to do.

Even if you make a union (either manually or [with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494689/is-it-possible-to-restrict-number-to-a-certain-range)), it probably won't be much fun, because TypeScript doesn't attempt to track the invariants.

```
// Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Hour'.
const q: Hour = 21 + 1;
```

You could add simple range validation yourself:

```
function MyComponent({value}: ComponentProps) {
  assert(value >= 0 && value <= 24);
```

You could enforce this more strictly with a [newtype](https://kubyshkin.name/posts/newtype-in-typescript/), similar to [@Lucas Maracaipe's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75801991/25507):

```
type Hour = number & { readonly __tag: unique symbol };
function validateHour(value: number): Hour {
  if (value < 0 || value > 24) {
    throw new Error('Hour must be between 0 and 24');
  }
  return value as Hour;
}

export interface ComponentProps {
  title: string;
  value: Hour;
}
```

Finally, if you really wanted, you could use React's [prop-types](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). Prop types are almost completely obsoleted by TypeScript, and I wouldn't recommend them, but their ability to do arbitrary runtime validation is something that TypeScript's type system can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You could make some superior/inferior condition :

```js
if ( value >= 0 && value < 25 ){
   ...doSomething
}
```

Hope I could help !