# Why doesn't Try[List[MyClass]] conform to Try[List[T <: MyClass]]?

Tags: scala, types

I am trying to define a method with the following signature:

```
def parse[T <: MyClass](statement: String): Try[List[T]] = {
```

My class is an abstract class:

```
sealed abstract class MyClass { }

case class MyClassChild(v: Int) extends MyClass
```

my `parse` method returns a Success(List[MyClassChild])

But the compiler complains with the following error:

```
Error:(124, 19) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.util.Try[List[parser.MyClass]]
 required: scala.util.Try[List[T]]
```

Why doesn't `scala.util.Try[List[parser.MyClass]]` conform to `scala.util.Try[List[T]]`, since `T <: MyClass` ?

Thank you

Comment: Because `parser.MyClass` is a [path dependent type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types).

Comment: I read that but I don't really understand what makes `MyClass` a path dependent type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` should be `>: MyClass` and `Try[List[T]] >: Try[List[MyClass]]` (List and also Try is [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question), so it will work) to confirm return type - because your function can't return bigger type than declared (see [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) ):

```
scala> trait A { type MT; def aaa[T <: MT]: List[T] = null.asInstanceOf[List[MT]] }
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[A.this.MT]
 required: List[T]


scala> trait A { type MT; def aaa[T >: MT]: List[T] = null.asInstanceOf[List[MT]] }
defined trait A
```

If you want `T <: MyClass` - you should change return type to `Try[List[MyClass]]`:

```
scala> trait A { type MT; def aaa[T <: MT]: List[MT] = null.asInstanceOf[List[MT]] }
defined trait A
```

In other words, you can't "shrink" `MyClass` to `T` even theoretically because it's bigger by `T <: MyClass` definition. `MyClass.asInstanceOf[T]` will give you type cast error with probability > 0, it's like `Any.asInstanceOf[String]`.

Comment: But I want `List[T] <: List[MyClass]`, isn't this possible?

Comment: just specify Try[List[parser.MyClass]] as return type or don't specify return type at all.