# Scala nested case class self-bounding inheritance

Tags: scala, generics, case-class

I'm currently working on a A* implementation in Scala. To accomplish a clean structure I would like to use a nested case class structure which implements a self-bounded trait. However, I experience some issues when implementing this in the Scala IDE. The following code will not compile:

```
trait A[T <: A[T]]

class B {

    case class C(int: Int) extends A[C] // A[this.C] won't work either

    def make = C(5)

}

object D {

    def foo[T <: A[T]](some: T) = {}

    val c = new B().make

    foo(c) // this does not compile

}
```

Is there any way I can make this structure work?

Comment: A nice explanation of path-dependent types can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you want this, but here's why it won't work as is:

The type of `D.c` is `B#C`. It is a path-dependent type where we don't know what instance of `B` it belongs to. However, `C` extends `A[C]`, which is the already the same as saying `A[this.C]` in that context, which is bound to a specific instance of `B`. `foo` sees the type parameter `T` as `B#C`, which is not the same as `b.C` for some `b`.

You have two options to make this compile.

Relax the constraints of `A` to `B#C`:

```
trait A[T <: A[T]]

class B {

    case class C(int: Int) extends A[B#C]

    def make = C(5)

}

object D {

    def foo[T <: A[T]](some: A[T]) = {}

    val c = new B().make

    foo(c)

}
```

Or handle the path-dependent type, so that `c` has type `b.C`:

```
trait A[T <: A[T]]

class B {

    case class C(int: Int) extends A[C]

    def make = C(5)

}

object D {

    def foo[T <: A[T]](some: A[T]) = {}

    val b = new B
    val c: b.C = b.make

    foo(c)

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This explained a lot!

Comment: The explicit type on `c` in the last example isn't actually necessary, I found.  I would love an explanation for why introducing the intermediate val `b` changes the inferred type of `c`.  I get that there is no name for the intermediate value without `b` but not how that matters to the inference.

Comment: I don't think there is a spec for type inference rules, so I'm at a loss there. I just don't think the type inferencer is smart enough in this case to do it all in one statement--similar to why you need to curry arguments like `def f(b: B)(c: b.C)`