# Path dependent types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to design an API for some database system in Haskell, and I would like to model the columns of this database in a way such that interactions between columns of different tables cannot get mixed up.

More precisely, imagine that you have a type to represent a table in a database, associated to some type:

```
type Table a = ...
```

and that you can extract the columns of the table, along with the type of the column:

```
type Column col = ...
```

Finally, there are various extractors. For example, if your table contains descriptions of frogs, a function would let you extract the column containing the weight of the frog:

```
extractCol :: Table Frog -> Column Weight
```

Here is the question: I would like to distinguish the origin of the columns so that users cannot do operations between tables. For example:

```
bullfrogTable = undefined :: Table Frog
toadTable = undefined :: Table Frog
bullfrogWeights = extractCol bullfrogTable
toadWeights = extractCol toadTable
-- Or some other columns from the toad table
toadWeights' = extractCol toadTable
-- This should compile
addWeights toadWeights' toadWeights
-- This should trigger a type error
addWeights bullfrogWeights toadWeights
```

I know how to achieve this in Scala (using path-dependent types, see [1]), and I have been thinking of 3 options in Haskell:

- not using types, and just doing a check at runtime (the current solution)
- the TypeInType extension to add a phantom type on the Table type itself, and pass this extra type to the columns. I am not keen on it, because the construction of such a type would be very complicated (tables are generated through complex DAG operations) and probably slow to compile in this context.
- wrapping the operations using a `forall` construct similar to the ST monad, but in my case, I would like the extra tagging type to actually escape the construction.

I am happy to have a very limited valid scoping for the construction of the same columns (i.e. columns from `table` and `(id table)` not being mixable), and I mostly care about the DSL feel of the API rather than the safety.

[1] [What is meant by Scala's path-dependent types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types)

**My current solution**

Here is what I ended up doing, using RankNTypes.

I still want to give users the ability to use columns how they see fit without having some strong type checks, and opt in if they want some stronger type guarantees: this is a DSL for data scientist who will not know the power of the Haskell side

Tables are still tagged by their content:

```
type Table a = ...
```

and columns are now tagged with some extra reference types, on top of the type of the data they contain:

```
type Column ref col = ...
```

Projections from tables to columns are either tagged or untagged. In practice, this is hidden behind a lens-like DSL.

```
extractCol :: Table Frog -> Column Frog Weight

data TaggedTable ref a = TaggedTable { _ttTable :: Table a }

extractColTagged :: Table ref Frog -> Column ref Weight

withTag :: Table a -> (forall ref. TaggedTable ref a -> b) -> b
withTag tb f = f (TaggedTable tb)
```

Now I can write some code as following:

```
let doubleToadWeights = withTag toadTable $ \ttoadTable ->
  let toadWeights = extractColTagged ttoadTable in
    addWeights toadWeights toadWeights
```

and this will not compile, as desired:

```
let doubleToadWeights =
  toadTable `withTag` \ttoads ->
     bullfrogTable `withTag` \tbullfrogs ->
       let toadWeights = extractColTagged ttoads
           bullfrogWeights = extractColTagged tbullfrogs
       in addWeights toadWeights bullfrogWeights -- Type error
```

From a DSL perspective, I believe it is not as straightforward as what one could achieve with Scala, but the type error message is understandable, which is paramount for me.

Comment: You seem to have a pretty good lay of the land in your listed options.  The only thing that comes to mind is [`reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) which you may be able to get to work for you with some cleverness.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the `reflection` package. My issue is that the signature of `reify` is essentially closed over the type being created, i.e. it does not escape. I am not familiar enough with the Haskell type system to understand if you can create a type out of a value (which sounds like a heresy in Haskell, and only allowed through a special compiler construct in Scala).

Comment: Nothing like Scala's path-dependent types are available in Haskell.  The "non-`fast`" reflection variant contains a mechanism by which you can a type representation of a value, but it's messy and your error messages would be horrid.  The only way to create a type with "intensional identity" (i.e. not equal to any other type) is through a scoped quantifier like `reify` or `runST`.  I would begin looking for mixed approaches, e.g. go with your option #2 but create a simplified phantom type that does not capture everything, combined with selective manual labeling or something.

Comment: Of course if you use template haskell your options widen.  E.g. you could generate a fresh top-level type for each table declaration and then use that to tag the columns.  I think you could get a minimal approximation of path-dependent types that way, actually.

Comment: `add a phantom type on the Table type itself, and pass this extra type to the columns` Why do the tables need to have a phantom type? Perhaps it would be enough if the columns where tagged with the phantom type of its origin table.

Comment: @danidiaz yes this is what I ended up doing, although it requires the introduction of a separate type. You can see what I eventually came up with in the edited answer.

Comment: @luqui thanks for your comments, I ended doing something as you suggested. I agree that template haskell would be nice, but it seems to have to many other downsides (compilation times, weird corner cases, lack of understandability) in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell does not (as far as I know) have path dependent types, but you can get some of the way by using rank 2 types. For instance the ST monad has a dummy type parameter `s` that is used to prevent leakage between invocations of runST:

```
runST :: (forall s . ST s a) -> a
```

Within an ST action you can have an STRef:

```
newSTRef :: a -> ST s (STRef s a)
```

But the STRef you get carries the `s` type parameter, so it isn't allowed to escape from the `runST`.